KRB5CCNAME is missing
The problem is I have no KRB5CCNAME in $_SERVER[] (php) for LDAP search.
I login to the server via kerberos gssapi, from Ubuntu to Windows Server 2012, using Samba.
On my site (PHP), I authorize with kerberos, checked it (it works), and want to find user with ldap_sasl connection, but for this I should have the KRB5CCNAME variable in $_SERVER, but it's not there.
My .htaccess file include these lines of config:
AuthName "Kerberos"
AuthType Kerberos
KrbAuthRealms DOMAIN.COM
KrbServiceName HTTP
Krb5Keytab /etc/httpd_test.keytab #tested, originally is httpd.keytab
KrbMethodNegotiate On
KrbMethodK5Passwd On
KrbLocalUserMapping On
Require valid-user

KrbSaveCredentials On

KrbDelegateBasic On
KrbVerifyKDC Off

And I tried but it does not work, either, with gssapi to authenticate by using this config:
AuthType GSSAPI
AuthName "GSSAPI"
GssapiBasicAuth On
#GssapiUseS4U2Proxy On
GssapiCredStore keytab:/etc/httpd_test.keytab #tested, originally is httpd.keytab
#GssapiCredStore client_keytab:/etc/httpd_test.keytab
GssapiCredStore ccache:/var/run/apache2/krb5ccache
GssapiDelegCcacheDir /var/run/apache2/clientcaches
GssapiDelegCcacheUnique On
Require valid-user

It's has the same trouble, and i don't use it because much of guides says about KrbSaveCredentials On had to be requirement for create KRB5CCNAME
A few details - versions of packages:
Apache2 (2.4.52)
Linux Ubuntu 22.04.4
PHP 8.2
Kerberos5 (1.19.2)
SMBD (4.15.13-Ubuntu)

Permissions for files:
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root httpd.keytab
-r--r----- 1 www-data www-data  httpd_test.keytab #tested
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root krb5.conf

Permissions for directories:
drwxrwxrwt  8 root root tmp
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root krb5ccache
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root krb5deleg

Apache username is www-data.
Authentication working fine, I can get access to the site. Defined login name is correct.
From my krb5.conf:
[libdefaults]
        default_realm = DOMAIN.COM

        dns_lookup_realm = true
        dns_lookup_kdc = true
        forwardable = true

        kdc_timesync = 1
        ccache_type = 4
        forwardable = true
        proxiable = true

And I checked ldap, it works fine.
With $ldapconn = ldap_connect($ldaphost) and with login and password in code they find what I need, but I want to ldap_sasl_bind with gssapi.
I suspect that I did not give the rights somewhere but I don't know.
Where might be the problem?
Update
Web server on HTTPS
Tested on Google Chrome (125.0.6422.77), Microsoft Edge (125.0.2535.67), Firefox (126.0)

Is the web server's HTTP/* principal marked as "trusted for (unconstrained) delegation"? Which browser / HTTP client are you using to access the website? And just to make sure – are you actually testing with Kerberos (Negotiate) auth, or are you testing with password-based Basic auth?

Also, use mod_auth_gssapi. When guides say that KrbSaveCredentials is a requirement, they mean it's a requirement for mod_auth_kerb – it's not somehow a universal requirement that no other module can implement.

Web server on HTTPS, i have a self-signed certificate;;
I check different browsers: Edge, Google Chrome, Mazilla (this one need to add some settings);;
About auth: i aunificate by kerberos, not a basic login/pass auth, it's simple because
I didn't enter my username and password anywhere;;
I understand about mod_auth_kerb and mod_auth_gssapi, but as I said, I tried both methods and with both of them I did not get KRB5CCNAME in order to commit ldap_sasl_bind;;
I'm sorry if I didn't put it that way in the question;;

Is the web server's Kerberos principal marked as "trusted for delegation"?

Actually, idk, how can i check that?

That depends on the KDC – if it's Active Directory, open the webserver account's settings in dsa.msc and it will have a "Delegation" tab. Your current httpd config is for the traditional unconstrained delegation, i.e. the "Trust this user for delegation to any service" option. (It lets the service fully impersonate the user, so naturally the service has to be approved like that – and Firefox needs delegation to be enabled in about:config as well.)

Baseline Kerberos authentication does not transfer user credentials. The only ticket the web server receives is for the web server itself.
For KRB5CCNAME to be set (and populated with the user's TGT or anything else), you additionally need to enable delegation of some type – either unconstrained delegation (where the client is requested to transfer the entire TGT to the server) or constrained delegation (where the KDC allows the server to impersonate the user).
Assuming your KDC is provided by Active Directory:

Delegation capabilities are configured per principal in AD user account settings (for the 'HTTP' service account, not for the client account).

Constrained delegation is entirely server-side and involves S4U, see the GssapiUseS4U2Proxy setting. I believe modern AD configures this as "Resource-Based Constrained Delegation" via PowerShell but I am unfamiliar.

Unconstrained delegation is "Trust this user for delegation to any service". It's supported by both Apache modules (GssapiDelegCcacheDir), and may require client-side configuration (Firefox has a separate about:config setting to allow delegation).
Unconstrained delegation is quite risky – the web server ends up gathering user TGTs so it becomes quite the attack target.
It also may be slow, because it involves the client requesting a new TGT with different flags, and some clients do not cache such TGTs, leading to an extra KDC request for every single HTTP request. (In comparison, service tickets for baseline Kerberos auth are always cached.)


